# How to remove delimiter and following string, after the delimiter appears for the second time, in all lines and columns

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a large table (millions of rows by hundreds of columns, tab-delimited) with the first three columns looking like this:

```
GT:DS:GP    0|0:0.181:0.827,0.165,0.008 0|0:0.181:0.827,0.165,0.008 0|0:0.181:0.827,0.165,0.008
GT:DS:GP    0|0:0.109:0.894,0.103,0.003 0|0:0.109:0.894,0.103,0.003 0|0:0.109:0.894,0.103,0.003
GT:DS:GP    0|0:0.004:0.996,0.004,0.000 0|0:0.004:0.996,0.004,0.000 0|0:0.004:0.996,0.004,0.000
GT:DS:GP    0|0:0.117:0.886,0.110,0.003 0|0:0.117:0.886,0.110,0.003 0|0:0.117:0.886,0.110,0.003
```

All remainder columns look like columns 2 and 3. I need a new file based on the first file, without the text that comes after the second colon (:). The output should look like the following:

```
GT:DS   0|0:0.181   0|0:0.181   0|0:0.181
GT:DS   0|0:0.109   0|0:0.109   0|0:0.109
GT:DS   0|0:0.004   0|0:0.004   0|0:0.004
GT:DS   0|0:0.117   0|0:0.117   0|0:0.117
```

I feel like it might be something on the lines of something I found in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642153/how-do-i-delete-everything-after-second-occurrence-of-quotes-using-the-command-l), but obviously the exit command tells it to stop after the first occurrence, so it does not work with multiple occurrences (in several lines/columns)...

```
awk -v RS=':' -v ORS=':' 'NR==1{print} NR==2{print; printf"\n";exit}' input > output
```

Output of this failed attempt was:

```
GT:DS:
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/\([^:]*:[^:]*\):[^:\t]*/\1/g' file
GT:DS   0|0:0.181       0|0:0.181       0|0:0.181
GT:DS   0|0:0.109       0|0:0.109       0|0:0.109
GT:DS   0|0:0.004       0|0:0.004       0|0:0.004
GT:DS   0|0:0.117       0|0:0.117       0|0:0.117
```